# ¿Cómo pausar un video que está dentro de un Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview

Tengo implementado `BottomBar` con 5 `Fragments` donde tengo en uno de ellos un `WebView` con la página de *Youtube*. El problema es que al reproducir un vídeo y cambio de `Fragment` en el `BottomBar` se sigue oyendo, y debería parar.

He probado con el método `onPause`, pero nada. El método `onStop`, no sé por qué se me detiene la aplicación. ¿Cuál había que usar en este caso?

```
public class Four_fragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);

        String url = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        WebView appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(url);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando un Webview para el video?

Comment: En el xml hay sólo un webView que ocupa toda la pantalla sí. Y dentro de la app uso YouTube y puedo reproducir el vídeo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como me has indicado que estás usando un `Webview` yo tuve el mismo problema el otro día y yo lo pausé haciendo referencia al método `onPause` y `onResume` del `WebView` dentro del método `onPause` y `onResume` del `Fragment`. Algo así:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    miWebview.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    miWebview.onPause();
}
```

Otra solución que ví por Internet pero que me parece un poco más un workaround que una solución sería cargar en el Webview una url vacía:

```
miWebview.loadUrl("");
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55443/discussion-on-answer-by-error404-como-pausar-un-video-que-esta-dentro-de-un-fra).